# OpenFOAM installation for Windows - \config.json: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: json, docker, windows-10, openfoam

I am trying to install OpenFOAM on Windows 10 following the instruction on the official website (http://www.openfoam.com/download/install-binary-windows.php).
When I click *OF_Env_Create* to initiate Docker environment I get an error message:

*open C:\Users\Admin.docker\machine\machines\default\config.json: The system cannot find the file specified.*

Any Idea how I can solve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any chance for you to provide an answer for this issue, if possible (assuming it was resolved), - so that others may benefit from it?